# Как дать условие для scroll()

Tags: jquery

Есть блок на сайте:

```
<div id="blc3"></div>
```

После перехода этого блок, появляется другой блок. 
Пример можно посмотреть в VK.com,  если прокрутить страницу вниз, то после закрытия всех левых блоков, ширина стены удлиняется. 
Как решить эту задачу?
Благодарю за внимание!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да всё просто!

Узнаем высоту блока `#blc3`:

```
var blc3_height = $('#blc3').height();
```

При скролле

```
$(window).scroll();
```

проверяем высоту скролла:

```
$(window).scrollTop();
```

Если высота скролла больше, чем высота блока `#blc3`, то расширяем другие блоки:

```
var blc3_height = $('#blc3').height()
,   if_max_width = false;

$(window).scroll(function() {
   var top_scroll = $(this).scrollTop();

   if(top_scroll > blc3_height && !if_max_width) {
      if_max_width = true;  
      $('.blocks').css('width', 500);
   }
   else if(top_scroll < blc3_height && if_max_width) {
      if_max_width = false;
      $('.blocks').css('width', 200);
   }
});
```